# Using Node.js child_process.exec() in a for loop e.g. pinging IP addresses one by one

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to ping each IP address in an array/JSON for their reachability. Here's a simple scenario:

```
var onlineCams = {};

for (var i = 0; i < ipList.cameras.length; i++) {
    var currentIp = ipList.cameras[i].ip;
    var currentIpStatus = "";
    var shellCmd = 'ping -c 1 ' + currentIp + ' | grep icmp* | grep bytes | wc -l';

    var child = exec(shellCmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (stdout.toString().trim() == '1') 
            currentIpStatus = "Online";
        else 
            currentIpStatus = "Offline";

    onlineCams[currentIp] = currentIpStatus;
    });
}
```

Sample output:

```
// console.log(ipList.cameras);
[ { id: 0, ip: '192.168.79.139' },
  { id: 1, ip: '192.168.79.16' } ]

// console.log(onlineCams);
{ '192.168.79.16': 'Online' }
```

There is only one IP address in `onlineCams` when there should be two. For some reason, .139 was skipped and I'm guessing it's because the `exec` thread overwrites itself before .139's results are returned. Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use a sync loop to manage multiple async operations.
You can either use [exec_sync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) or refactor your code.

A nice solution would be using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and for node.js [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) is my preferred library.

Then you can write something like this (maybe imrpove it!):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var ipList = {
    cameras: [{
        ip: 'yahoo.com'
    }, {
        ip:'google.com'
    },{
        ip: 'fake.fake'
    }]
};
var onlineCams = {};
var promises = [];
function checkIp(ip) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var shellCmd = 'ping -c 1 ' + ip + ' | grep icmp* | grep bytes | wc -l';
        exec(shellCmd, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            var result = {};
            result[ip] = stdout.toString().trim() === '1' ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < ipList.cameras.length; i++) {
    promises.push(checkIp(ipList.cameras[i].ip));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```